# Customize and bind DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the correct way to bind a database table in a DataGrid in WPF through a ControlTemplate?

I tried in this following way because I need to insert this DataGrid in a ControlTemplate used by a ContentControl used by a DataTemplate.

I have a DataTemplate called Desktop_layout

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Desktop_Layout">
```

in this DataTemplate there is a ContentControl

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
            Template="{StaticResource Card_TableMainTracking_Desktop}"/>`
```

and the ControlTemplate contains a DataGrid

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Card_TableMainTracking_Desktop">
...
<DataGrid 
x:Name="dataGrid1">  //here where I will customize my DataGrid
</DataGrid>
```

Now I need to bind this DataGrid to a database table.

I already tried to add this method in MainVindow.xaml.cs (MainWindow.xaml is where I use the DataTemplate)

```
    private void BindData() {
        String selectstatement = "select * from dbo.Bicycles order by actualPosition ASC ";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectstatement, ConnDB_UI);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
```

but of course dataGrid1 here is not visible so I have an error.

Answer (score 0):

Either bind the `DataGrid` to a public property of the `Content` of the `ContentControl` or handle the `Loaded` event for the `DataGrid` and set its `ItemsSource` property programmatically once the template has been applied to an element:

```
private void dataGrid1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid1 = (DataGrid)sender;

    String selectstatement = "select * from dbo.Bicycles order by actualPosition ASC ";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectstatement, ConnDB_UI);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Card_TableMainTracking_Desktop">
    ...
    <DataGrid  x:Name="dataGrid1"
               Loaded="dataGrid1_Loaded">
    </DataGrid>
    ...
```